# What is the best way to synchronize access to an object outside ActorSystem in Akka.NET?

Tags: asp.net, akka.net

I have an ASP.NET application that accesses a class that wraps a Dictionary and may be accessed during page request handling. Akka.NET actor also obtains a reference to that class instance during initialization and may access the class any time.

What's the best way to synchronize access to that Dictionary without breaking Akka.NET's flow? Can using .NET Monitor's break Akka.NET threadpool somehow? I can't change entire application logic to actors and wrap the cache in an actor (yet) so I'd like to hear about (least bad) alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

As long as your in this hybrid scenario. I'd recommend to keep it simple and use a ConcurrentDictionary type to synchronise access.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the opportunity to refactor and have dictionary data served by designated actor, that will be the best approach IMHO.

Comment: Thanks but as I mentioned - I can't do it. Whatsmore in a web app there will always be a part of code that is not in ActorSystem, Pulling a lot of data via messages is also not efficient performance-wise.

Comment: didn't get that... was reading twice... so I need to get new glasses :-)
Will concurrent dictionary work for you?
I was using it with a high level of threads asking for data - and the concurrent dictionary was working like a charm

Comment: It may but I don't know how does locking like that affect the actor system of the actor that's waiting on the lock. Can it reduce the resources available to the actor system somehow? Is mailbox'es ability to accept messages adversely affected?

Comment: so - the point is that actor or other entity need to get entry from a dictionary.
Using classic approach - you need to lock dictionary object before you get data to be in a thread safe  position. 
So in this case adding or updating can be a issue. please see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx 
---
Why you think about limiting actor activity?

Comment: in an extreme case, if there are as many locks as there are threads used by actor system, locking the actor system could (?) delay actor inbox processing, lead to heartbeats not propagating in cluster, etc.